# rxjs websocket: heartbeat and reconnection

Tags: angular, websocket, rxjs

I am trying to implement a RXJS websocket client, who automatically reconnects on error and in case it doesn't get an heartbeat from server.

The problem is that on error, the reconnection attempts don't follow the schedule I tried to set (once every 10 seconds for at most 10 times). In fact, at the beginning, the rate is once every 2 seconds, then it starts to make multiple requests simultaneously, and then, after reconnection, it still fires connection requests.

What am I doing wrong?

```
init(wsUrl: string, wsAuthToken: string, reconnect?: boolean) {
    this.connected$ = new Subject<boolean>();
    if (this._heartbeatSub) {
      this._heartbeatSub.unsubscribe();
    }

    if (!this.socket$ || this.socket$.closed)
      this.socket$ = webSocket({
        protocol: wsAuthToken,
        url: wsUrl,
        deserializer: (val) => {
          if (val.data === "H") return "H";
          else return JSON.parse(val.data);
        },
        serializer: (val) => {
          if (val === "H") {
            return "H";
          } else return JSON.stringify(val);
        },
        openObserver: {
          next: () => {
            this.loggedOut = false;
            this.connected$.next(true);
            this._heartbeatSub = timer(0, 15000)
              .pipe(
                concatMap(() =>
                  race(
                    of("timeout").pipe(delay(15000)),
                    this.socket$.pipe(filter((msg) => msg === "H"))
                  )
                )
                // filter((resp) => resp === "timeout")
              )
              .subscribe((resp) => {
                if (resp === "timeout") {
                  this.socket$.complete();
                } else this.socket$.next("H");
              });
          },
        },
        closeObserver: {
          next: () => {
            this._heartbeatSub.unsubscribe();
            this.connected$.next(false);
            if (this.socket$) this.socket$.complete();
            if (!this.loggedOut) this.init(wsUrl, wsAuthToken, true);
          },
        },
      });
    this.socket$
      .pipe(
        reconnect ? this.reconnect : (o) => o,
        filter((msg) => msg !== "H")
      )
      .subscribe((msg) => {
        if (msg.header.hasOwnProperty("rid")) {
          const subj = this.subjects.get(
            msg.header.ssid + "-" + msg.header.uid + "-" + msg.header.rid
          );
          subj.next(msg);
          subj.complete();
          this.subjects.delete(
            msg.header.ssid + "-" + msg.header.uid + "-" + msg.header.rid
          );
        } else
          this.subjects.get(msg.header.ssid + "-" + msg.header.uid).next(msg);
      });
    return this.connected$.asObservable().pipe(take(1));
  }

  close() {
    this.loggedOut = true;
    this.connected$.next(false);
    this._heartbeatSub.unsubscribe();
    this.socket$.complete();
    this.socket$ = undefined;
  }

  private reconnect(observable: Observable<any>): Observable<any> {
    let tries = 0;
    return observable.pipe(
      retryWhen((errors) =>
        errors.pipe(
          tap((val) => console.log("websocket: Try to reconnect", val)),
          delay(10000),
          take(10)
        )
      )
    );
  }
```

**EDIT**

I modified my `openObserver` this way

```
        openObserver: {
      next: () => {
        this.loggedOut = false;
        this.reconnecting = false;
        this.connected$.next("connected");
        this._heartbeatSub = timer(0, 15000)
          .pipe(
            concatMap(() =>
              race(
                of("timeout").pipe(delay(15000)),
                this.connected$.pipe(
                  tap((val) => console.log(val)),
                  filter((status) => status === "error")
                ),
                this.socket$.pipe(
                  filter((msg) => msg === "H"),
                  take(1)
                )
              )
            )
            // filter((resp) => resp === "timeout")
          )
          .subscribe((resp) => {
            if (resp === "timeout" || resp === "error") {
              this._heartbeatSub.unsubscribe();
              this.init(wsUrl, wsAuthToken, true);
            } else this.socket$.next("H");
          });
      },
    },
```

And my `closeObserver` this way

```
closeObserver: {
      next: () => {
        if (!this.loggedOut) this.connected$.next("error");

      },
    },
```

But still, I have a problem: the retries are fired every 13 seconds instead of, even if delay in `reconnect` is 10 seconds. Also, the retry limit is not taken in account

Comment: I believe there is a bug in heartbeat sub. could you try to add take(1) here ? `this.socket$.pipe(filter((msg) => msg === "H"), take(1))`

Comment: It didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

try this reconnect handler

```
 private reconnect(observable: Observable<any>): Observable<any> {
    let tries = 0;
    return observable.pipe(
      retryWhen((attempts) =>
        attempts.pipe(
          switchMap((err, i) => i < 10 ? timer(10000) : throwError(err), (a,b,i) => i),
 // switchMap selector is just needed for the next tap with console.log. feel free to remove it
          tap((i) => console.log("websocket: Try to reconnect. attempt: ", val + 1)),
        )
      )
    );
  }
```

or build your own, following example at the bottom of [retryWhen operator page](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/error_handling/retrywhen)

Comment: It keeps doing the same thing. I don't know where the 2 seconds thing comes out

Answer (score 0):

This code looks similar to this one: https://github.com/lamisChebbi/ng-realtime-dashboard/blob/master/src/app/services/data.service.ts

I tried that out and also found issues with the reconnect. My guess is:
When the connection fails `closeObserver` is called. Here `this.init` is called which creates a new WebSocket connection. And I think as this is a new try there is no error yet. So `retryWhen` just passes it through. When the error happens the retry logic starts, but also `closeObserver` is called again. So it starts all over.

The time between trying to connect and the connection error was 2 to 5 seconds in my case when I tried to connect to a not running server on localhost.

See also my issue on GitHub: https://github.com/lamisChebbi/ng-realtime-dashboard/issues/20

I got it working by adding a variable `inRetryMode` which starts with false and is reset to false in `openObserver`. And:

```
private reconnect(observable: Observable<any>): Observable<any> {
    let tries = 0;
    return observable.pipe(
        retryWhen((errors) => errors.pipe(
            tap((val) => {
                this.inRetryMode = true;
                console.log("websocket: Try to reconnect", val))
            },
            delay(10000),
            take(10)
        ))
    );
}
```

And then calling `init()` in `closeObserver` only if not `inRetryMode`.
Maybe it would be better to add the retry logic in `closeObserver` only?